# Require field if shown in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form where if someone clicks a link it opens an input for them to fill in their credit card number.  I am trying to make it so that if this form is shown and they click add it will tell them a CC# is required.  If they click cancel, it will just hide the form.

When the user clicks the link this code shows the form

```
function lnkAddCc_Click(sender, args) {
                //this is overkill, but just to make sure inputs are clean
                $('#addCCRow').find('input').each(function () { (this).value = ''; });
                $('#<%= fullCcNumber.ClientID %>').val('');
                $('#addCCRow').hide();
                $('#addCCLabel').hide();
                $('#addCCRow').show();
            }
```

when they click cancel this code shuts the form

```
function btnCancel_Click(sender, args) {
                args.set_cancel(true);
                $('#addCCRow').find('input').each(function () { (this).value = ''; });
                $('#<%= fullCcNumber.ClientID %>').val('');
                $('#addCCRow').hide();
                $('#addCCLabel').show();
            var validate = $('#aspnetForm').validate();
            validate.resetForm();
```

I can't use a validator on my

```
<tr class="AltRow" id="addCCRow" style="display: none">
                <td><label style="color: black;">Credit, Debit or ATM Card Number:</label></td>
                <td style="text-align: right; width: 100%;">
                    <input ID="newCard0" MaxLength="4" size="6" onkeyup="CopyCardInput(this)" />&nbsp;-&nbsp;
                    <input ID="newCard1" MaxLength="4" size="6" onkeyup="CopyCardInput(this)" />&nbsp;-&nbsp;
                    <input ID="newCard2" MaxLength="4" size="6" onkeyup="CopyCardInput(this)" />&nbsp;-&nbsp;
                    <input ID="newCard3" MaxLength="4" size="6" onkeyup="CopyCardInput(this)" /><br />
```

because it requires whether its visible or not.  How do I get it to require only when it's visible?

Comment: Your show/cancel code could add/remove the required attribute as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in an object to the validate option, and override the ignore option:

```
var validate = $('#aspnetForm').validate({
  ignore: ""
});
validate.resetForm();
```